# Google Drive CORS

Tags: cors, google-drive-api

Is there a reason why Google Drive does not set Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* on the file data available at downloadUrl. 
 I am interested in downloading binary files from Google Drive using ajax/CORS. 
However, the only way to achieve this seems to be through a proxy.

Comment: Does my answer help explain? Please let me know and I'll update if not.

Comment: Yes, you did answer the question. However, I was hoping for some guidance on making CORS requests to Google Drive. I recently found that Google Drive does accept CORS requests if a valid access token is provided.

Comment: Maybe you'd get a better response if you asked this as a new question? I don't know the ins and outs of Google Drive hence my answer to your question here only covers CORS in general.

Comment: @MaxFerguson Could you write an answer to this question which details your findings on using an access token?

Comment: Oh. Never mind... I assume you are talking about when you need to authenticate, whereas I'm looking at the case where the content is available to anyone with the link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### With [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)

Because it would be a huge security hole.

Any website you visited would be able to grab files from your Google Drive if you were logged into Google.

### Without [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) or with [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Credentials)

You could ask [Why is the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header necessary](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/44058/8340) at all?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not true - if the response has the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header and does not have `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`, the response cannot be read if credentials are sent (i.e. only anonymous requests can be made).

Comment: @alf yes you would need that header too. I was assuming it was content that requires a login so I took it that the credentials header was implied.

Comment: is there any way to convert client api request to XMLHttpRequest,I am using web worker and we can not load client rest api in web worker so i need rename, upload, update this kind of functionality with ajax request