# @font-face not working in my blogger blog

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am using custom web font in my blogger blog. It is not working since few weeks ago. There is a solution for this error that i show on stackflow website but i can't apply it for blogger blog because there is no .htaccess file in blogger. please some one help me. my font face code here. and my website is http://vishwatestblog.blogspot.com/

```html
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fmmalithix';
    src: url('https://googledrive.com/host/0ByuGuHHrxa5GY0JSNTR4TUhaZ3c');
    src: url('https://googledrive.com/host/0ByuGuHHrxa5GY0JSNTR4TUhaZ3c?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('https://googledrive.com/host/0ByuGuHHrxa5GMm45RW5zWkd1Slk') format('woff2'),
         url('https://googledrive.com/host/0ByuGuHHrxa5GUUJGS0dxME5XbDQ') format('woff'),
         url('https://googledrive.com/host/0ByuGuHHrxa5GN2xhWmQ2bHdDRDA') format('truetype'),
         url('https://googledrive.com/host/0ByuGuHHrxa5GRzhxSzRhN1dBTEE#fmmalithix') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

Comment: Special my custom web font not working on firefox, internet explorer and google chrome (new version) web browser.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the font files doesn't have the CORS headers and thats the reason, you aren't able to see the font being applied.

Also, as the files are being downloaded from googledrive, you need to be signed in to access the file.

I dont think you can host the font files on a google drive and access without authorization.

you can check it yourself, font urls you mentioned throw a 404 if you open in incognito mode.

Comment: what is the CORS headers. i can't understand that. please simplify the answer.

Comment: A detailed explanation of CORS is found here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS .

Comment: to be brief, not all the resources on internet can be used as resources on a particular web page , unless they are allowed through CORS header. Cors is a response header, that controls and gates the sites on which they can be used. Here is a detailed explanation : http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43639/why-is-the-access-control-allow-origin-header-necessary/44058#44058

Comment: A similar question about CORS headers about Google drive : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026016/google-drive-cors . I hope your confusion can be cleared with the above links.

Answer (score -1):

Please Check, you have correctly placed the font file and the google drive directory.

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family: 'Font Family';
    src: url('source.ttf') format('truetype'); ---> Font Type
}
```