# How to directly upload files from google drive to amazon s3?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, axios, google-drive-api

I want to directly upload some files from google drive to amazon s3 but unable to do so.

I dont know, how can i directly upload the files from google drive to amazon s3.

I tried getting the download link using python and google api.

but when I try to upload to amazon s3 I'm getting errors:

```
      axios
      .get("https://drive.google.com/u/0/uc?id="+id+"&export=download", {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
        withCredentials: false,
        headers:{
          'Authorization':'Bearer: <access_token>',
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        }
      })
      .then((response:any) => Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary'))
      .then((data:any)=>{
        console.log(data)
      })
```

**EROR**

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Can anyone please tell me, how can i resolve this error?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a browser? Or Node.js?

Comment: @jarmod trying to do in a browser.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026016/google-drive-cors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Drive CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026016/google-drive-cors)

Comment: @jarmod Doesn't answer my question, what should i do to make a successful request? Should i use credentials: true ?

Comment: You can't download from Google Drive on a webpage served on another domain.  You'll at the least need to perform this download on a server you control, if not do all of the work on that server.

Answer (score 1):

you got the data from drive then;
with [aws-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) package you can create

`s3 = new AWS.S3(....)`

then use `s3.putObject` [method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html)

Answer (score 1):

Manage to find the answer and posting this as answer for anyone who is looking for same:

First you need a downloadable link which you can construct using file id:

Here it is:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/"+file.id+'?alt=media'
```

Then you can make a GET request with your google access token:

```
'Authorization','Bearer '+accessToken
```

This way you can download file from google drive which you can upload to s3.