# Backbone fetch() error when get JSON file from Google-Drive

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

When use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[stylesheet - ID]">` //**True**
and use `<img class="item-left-b" src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[image - ID]">` //**True**
but this

```
var $Items = new Backbone.Collection;
$Items.url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[Items JSON file - ID]';
$Items.fetch();
```

//**Error**

**How i can get JSON file like css file or image using Backbone.Collection?**

Im live in syria, in a U.S.-sanctioned, i cannot use one of them Bitbucket, SourceForge, GitLab, Github and CloudForge Repository Hosts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my JavaScript code receive a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error, while Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i)

Comment: This is probably a better duplicate: [Google Drive CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24026016/google-drive-cors)

Comment: I want to get JSON file like css file,

Comment: Have you read the links about CORS? You need a browser extension or a proxy server.

Comment: It's possible that the server sets CORS headers when you use an access token.

Comment: If you mean about when fetch JSON, i tried vpn.
Repository Hosts Sites they ask for confirmation message,They disable the entire account if you open it once without VPN.

Comment: I'm not running a server, I just want to use Google-drive as database

Comment: Have you read the linked questions?